# Query unique date to cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

In my database dates is stored in miliseconds as string. How to query unique dates considering only month and day and count how many date share same day?

Comment: @Selvin just a silly requirenment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide by 1000 to get seconds, then use the [`unixepoch` modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get date, and use `strftime` to output only the year and month:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', DateMillis / 1000, 'unixepoch'),
       COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a date, use date type. Sqlite may not have it. But please, do not use it as string! I would suggest you to store integer to store miliseconds sice epoch. Use bindLong() and such. Unfortunately, you have to make some computations yourself in code. Just compute first and last milisecond of each day. Then you would be able to use WHERE timestamp BETWEEN first_day_milisecond AND last_day_milisecond, using even indexes.
You can select min and max of timestamp to try only days between them.

If you need to do this frequently or over a lot of data, I suggest to store date in multiple columns as integers for year, month, day. Depends on what you have to do with time, miliseconds since midnight. Or more columns of hour, minute, second and miliseconds.

I think it is much easier to format string date from bunch of numbers than parsing those numbers from a string. Definitely easier to compare them inside database.